# Proof by Elements to Show $D^{c} ⊆ A^{c}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Use proof by elements to verify that for all nonempty sets $A$, $B$, and $D$ if $A ⊆ B$, $D^{c} ⊆ B^{c}$, then $D^{c} ⊆ A^{c}$.

Here's the proof I have written so far. I have gotten feedback that I am missing steps and have used incorrect algebra, but I can't see where the error in my logic is:

Proof by elements:

$\forall x, x∈D^{c} → x∈B^{c}$ since $D^{c} ⊆ B^{c}$

$→ x∈A^{c}$ since $A ⊆ B \iff B^{c} ⊆ A^{c}$

So, by definition of containment, $D^{c} ⊆ A^{c}$, $\forall x$.

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @JamesTaylor The final $\forall x$ should be removed. But I wouldn't deem this proof incorrect or incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use less symbols and more words.

The aim is to show that, if $x\in D^c$, then $x\in A^c$.

So, let $x\in D^c$. By hypothesis, $x\in B^c$, that is, $x\notin B$. Since $A\subseteq B$, we also have $x\notin A$ (otherwise $x\in B$). So $x\in A^c$.

Your proof is good, anyway.

Comment: One has to wonder. Had I been a tad quicker, do you think that you'd have received that downvote and I'd have received the two additional upvotes? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I didn't downvote, of course: paraphrasing Gauss, it would have been like downvoting myself. `;-)`

Comment: I'm sure that you weren't the one who downvoted, I was just a bit surprised by the downvote. [I guess that my answer is isomorphic and your answer isn't...](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53122/mathematical-urban-legends/53905#comment134523_53905) :-P

Answer (score 2):

It's quite tempting to use quantifiers and connectives when starting to write proofs. But nothing beats the clarity of plain English. Because you've got the basic idea, but the proof is not very well written. Instead, I'd suggest something of the following nature:

> Let $x\in D^c$ be an arbitrary element. By the assumption $D^c\subseteq B^c$ we have that $x\in B^c$. Therefore $x\notin B$, and since $A\subseteq B$, it is impossible that $x\in A$, since in that case $x\in B$. Therefore $x\in A^c$.

This is, essentially, what you wrote, only in English, and slightly more elaborate.

Comment: +1 I thought the written out version was actually really helpful. Thank you.